# function to take a number or vector of numbers, divide them all by their smallest value, and round results, in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that takes a number or vector of numbers, divides them all by their smallest value, and rounds the results to the nearest whole number.

I have tried:

```
 divide_and_round <- function(nums) {
    my_min <- min(nums, na.rm = TRUE)
    divided <- nums/my_min
    rounded <- round(divided)
    return(rounded)
  }

test <- c(1:5, NA)

divide_and_round(test)
```

Which only returns the numbers in test. Is the problem having to do with object type? Or something else? Thank you

Comment: Your min value is one, so you will get the same!

Comment: Besides, make sure to take care of `x/0`